# How to properly implement Local Notifications to run daily in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I tried implemented it `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` and then tried to schedule next day's notification in `WillPresentNotification`. It worked until the application was in foreground but as soon as it went background it stopped scheduling for next day.

I tried using `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` but the problem is that it will display same notification daily however my requirement is to display different notification daily for unlimited period until user stops it from within the application or via iOS itself.

Is there some way that I can modify the title and body of the next notification to be displayed using `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample to repeat an alarm everyday at **09:30** by using local notification in Xamarin iOS, you could have a look:

```
// 1
var dateComponents = new NSDateComponents();
dateComponents.Hour = 9;
dateComponents.Minute = 30;
var trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(dateComponents, true);

// 2
var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
content.Title = "Daily reminder";
content.Body = "Enjoy your day!";

var requestID = "request_" + id;
var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);

// 3
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) => {
    if (err != null)
    {
    }
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned already, I already achieved this result, the problem is I need different the content Title and content Body for each notification. How can I do that?

Comment: @MujtabaAli If so, you'd better use remote notification. The body and title can be updated every day by a customed push server. If you use local notification, you need to cancel and create local notification every day.

Comment: Well, remote notifications won't work in my case. And I have no problem in cancelling and creating local notification, real problem is where do I do this so that it runs even if the app is in background. The actual requirement is to pick data from the app database and present as notification. I tried earlier by scheduling notifications for 30 days in advance so that if user wont open the app for 30 days then still he will receive them but I need something tedious. Thanks.

Comment: @MujtabaAli It can not be setted when the app is closed. If using local notification, we only can create or canel when the app is launched or is active in background. If local notification can do all the things with the same with remote notification. Then remote notification has no meaning.

Comment: Hmm, that is absurd. Remote notification serve completely different purpose. It allows the app dev/owner to relay messages to app users and that too will only work when the app has access to internet. While local notifications are displayed locally to the app and those are to be defined when the app is developed and there is no need for the device to be connected to internet which is the case with my app which is offline. The only requirement is to display different notification daily which shouldn't be hard at all. I am amazed with all the trouble I am having with iOS as opposed to Android.

Comment: @MujtabaAli Could you share some sample different contents between each day? You're right, remote notification need network, if updated notification isn't related to network news. It's worth to achieve that by local notification.

Comment: I have a database of quotes from famous persons so it will be like
Title: "Quote from Person Name"
Description: "Actual quote from the person in detail which could be a little large requiring user to click if they want to read it completely."
There are thousands of these in the database so I will be selecting them randomly and display it.

Comment: @MujtabaAli Okey, if using local notification to achieve this. The best problem to update notification need user to lauch app next time. If no, the notification will not be updated or setted new one successfully.